# Simple codeigniter base directory-like function/definition for relative directory structure

Tags: url, codeigniter, relative-path

I'm developing a website with codeigniter, and I have a simple issue.

For html and styles I'm using `base_url()` for paths to work, but in html source a full path including http://

My folder structure is like this:

```
application/
system/
my_template/
    *styles.css
    *images/
    *etc.etc.
index.php
```

when I'm on index.php/controller/method/param1/param2, I want to set e.g css path like this:

```
<link href="../../../my_template/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

But with using base_url() they become like this:

```
<link href="http://www.site.com/my_template/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

How can I do this for css and `<script>` tags ? I'm sure I'm missing a simple step, but could not find it. I'm using CI 2.03.

Thanks,

Comment: Why can't you just use `href="/my_template/styles.css"`?

Comment: @birderic - does that (putting / in href attribute) work on all server configurations ?

Comment: Yes.  It is referencing the root directory of the web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/` to reference a file relative to the root directory of your web site.

Both paths will reference the same file assuming you are on http://www.site.com/.

```
<link href="/my_template/styles.css" ... />

<link href="http://www.site.com/my_template/styles.css" ... />
```